# GetTickCount() function ->Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I was porting the `cpp` code to `objective C`.And i came across this `GetTickCount()` function.

Will `Objective C` support `GetTickCount()` function?

How to get the current timer value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the result from `+[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` is good enough for your needs? `NSTimeInterval` is a 64it double measured in seconds *(and many decimals :))*

Comment: How will i find the GetTickCount in Milliseconds..is it 10 to the power 3.I tried with that and i'm getting the value as zero.

Comment: GetTickCount returns a DWORD.Means is it a unsigned long integer.

Comment: @ron If you want milliseconds just multiply by 1000, make sure not to trunk the time interval before multiplying.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [that](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1398/_index.html).

`mach_absolute_time()` looks like the most precise time measurement for you. There complete sample code to get it work.

Comment: Please add some detail to your answer. You can rewrite the docs you linked to in your own words, or add some appropriate quotes from them, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `clock()` function, from `time.h`

http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/CPU-Time.html